# Alert is not get called in the onSubmit method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html code, and i expect when i submit, an alart message appears.

```
<input id="reportForm" type="submit" value="Submit Report" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

and here is the js code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#reportForm').submit(function () {
        alert("Thanks for your report.");
    }); 
});
```

Unfortunately, it does not call the alert!

Comment: `submit()` can only be attached to <form> elements.

Comment: assign id to your form and try ('#formid').submit();..and it should work....you can bind submit on form not on button....if you want button use...$('btnid').click();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submit() event handler can only be bound to an form element (not to a input element, as you have done).

You have two options:

(1) Bind the action(s) to the form submission, by changing your HTML to something along these lines --

```
<form id="reportForm">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Report" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Or; (2) Bind the action(s) to the button click, by changing your javascript, like so --

```
$('#reportForm').click(function(){
   alert("Thanks for your report.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Submit events are triggered when you try to submit a form. If you wrap the field inside a `<form>` tag and target that element it should work.

```
<form id="reportForm">
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit Report" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
```

Comment: So, the id should mention the form not the button. right?